# Is reverse proxy chaining possible for HTTPS?

Tags: reverse-proxy, https

We have a public web server which needs to receive HTTPS requests from a customer system over HTTPS:

```
Our system <--- HTTPS Reverse Proxy <-- Customer system
```

Unfortunately the Customer requires specific firewall setting which our reverse proxy can only provide with considerable effort and costs.

Question: could we use a second HTTPS Reverye Proxy as an "adapter"

```
Our system <--- HTTPS Reverse Proxy <--- "compatible" HTTPS Reverse Proxy <-- Customer system
```

or is this definitely impossible for HTTPS connections?

Comment: Some reverse proxy can upstream the SSL connection if that is what you are asking. What are the compatible options you have to pick from?

Comment: @Drifter104 the customer system fails to connect unless we remove some SSL Cipher Suites - we can't do this as the configuration might get overwritten by every firewall update. We need a alternative which is less fragile.